# Generate reports for unit test results(Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, report

Is there any way to generate reports for our test results from visual studio?( C# + Selenium Webdriver) I'm using NUnit as Unit testing framework(Running tests via NUnit GUI), So basically NUnit generates XML file for test execution. I'm writing XSLT's to generate the HTML reports. I'm looking for something like TestNG where we can generate reports for our tests(Java + selenium webdriver).
Suggestions Welcome